# Display Last Week Records & Delete Previous Records in iPhone Application using Sqlite3 database

Tags: iphone, database, datetime, sqlite

I want to display last week records & delete previous records in my iPhone application.

So I'm getting one week later date-time by using,

```
//Now
nowDate = [entryDateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

//1 week previous
weekDate = [entryDateFormat stringFromDate:[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval: -604800.0]];
```

Then, executing SQL query like

```
NSString *selectSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM tblTest Where Time between \"%@\" and \"%@\"", weekDate, nowDate];
```

So getting value of Query ::

```
SELECT * FROM tblTest Where Time between "04-02-2013 17:20:36" and "11-02-2013 17:20:36";
```

Same as for Delete previous records

```
Delete FROM tblTest Where Time < "04-02-2013 17:20:36";
```

So, it'll work for only 1st, 2nd & 3rd of current date.

It'll not executes for previous month's dates like '30-01-2013' & '31-01-2013'.

I've also try for this:

```
Delete FROM tblTest Where Time < DATE('now','-7 days');
```

But no results.:(

What are functions for sqlite side, so we can perform operation based on those functions and get exact values for last week records.?

Please help me for this situation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all,

At saving time,

```
NSTimeInterval currentTimeStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
NSNumber *currentTimeStampObj = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: currentTimeStamp];

[currentTimeStampObj retain];
```

and store this into database as new 'entry time' field.

While Displaying Data & Delete previous data

```
//Date Formatter
NSDateFormatter *entryDateFormat;

//Now Date & Previous Date
NSString *nowDate, *weekDate;

NSNumber *currentNowTimeStamp, *pastWeekDateTimeStamp;

//Today
nowDate = [entryDateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSTimeInterval currentTimeStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
currentNowTimeStamp = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:currentTimeStamp];

[currentNowTimeStamp retain];

NSLog(@" Time :::: %@", currentNowTimeStamp);

//Past Week Date
weekDate = [entryDateFormat stringFromDate:[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval: -604800.0]];

currentTimeStamp = [[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval: -604800.0] timeIntervalSince1970];
pastWeekDateTimeStamp = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: currentTimeStamp];

[pastWeekDateTimeStamp retain];

NSLog(@" Past Week Time :::: %@", pastWeekDateTimeStamp);
```

Query ::

```
NSString *deleteSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Delete FROM tblTest Where entry time < \"%@\"", pastWeekDateTimeStamp];
```

Result :: `Delete FROM tblTest Where entry time < "1360392911.010868"`

```
NSString *selectSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM tblTest Where Time between \"%@\" and \"%@\"", pastWeekDateTimeStamp, currentNowTimeStamp];
```

Result :: `SELECT * FROM tblTest Where entry time between "1360392911.010868" and "1360997711.010534"`

And I got exact solution what I wanted.

Cheers..!!

Happy Coding..

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite, timestamps [should be stored with the year field first](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime),
i.e., in the format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`.